# Show the current page after clicking the button with the route in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have tried using exact in the route tag but the link is refreshing but the pages are not getting refreshed. Here is my code.I have also tried adding exact on each route tag but its still not working. The links are getting refreshed to say reports or products but the content on the page remain that of the home file.

This is my **app.js**, I have imported all the component files:

```
<Navbar/>
 <Router>
  <Sidebar/>
  <Switch>
   <Route exact  Path='/' component={Home}/>
   <Route exact Path='/reports' component={Reports}/>
   <Route exact  Path='/products' component={Product}/>
   <Route  exact Path='/services' component={Services}/>
   <Route  exact Path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
   <Route  exact Path='/signup'component={Signup}/>
  </Switch>
 </Router>
```

This is my **Sidebar.js**:

```
function Sidebar() {
    const [sidebar,setSidebar]=useState(false)
    const showSidebar=()=>setSidebar(!sidebar);
    return (
        <>
        <IconContext.Provider  value={{color:'#fff'}}>
        <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu2 active':'nav-menu2'}>
        <ul className='nav-menu2-items' onClick={showSidebar}>
     
        {SidebarData.map((item,index)=>{
           return(
               <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
               <Link to={item.path}>
               {item.icon}
               <span>
                   {item.title}
             </span>
               </Link>
              </li>
           );
        })
    }
        </ul> 
        </nav>
        </IconContext.Provider>
       </>
    );
}
```

and this is my **datafile:**

```
export const SidebarData=[
     {
     title:'Home',
     path:'/',
     icon:<AiIcons.AiFillHome/>,
     cName: 'nav-text'
},
{
    title:'Reports',
    path:'/reports',
    icon:<IoIcons.IoIosPaper/>,
    cName: 'nav-text'
},
{
    title:'Products',
    path:'/products',
    icon:<IoIcons.IoMdRibbon/>,
    cName: 'nav-text'
},
{
    title:'Services',
    path:'/services',
    icon:<IoIcons.IoIosPeople/>,
    cName: 'nav-text'
},
{
    title:'Contact us',
    path:'/contact',
    icon:<AiIcons.AiFillMail/>,
    cName: 'nav-text'
},
{
    title:'Sign Up',
    path:'/signup',
    icon:<FaIcons.FaUserAlt/>,
    cName: 'nav-text'
}
]
```

Comment: Maybe the `Path` should be changed to `path`

Answer (score 1):

path should be in small letters

```
<Router>
  <Sidebar/>
  <Switch>
   <Route exact  path='/' component={Home}/>
   <Route exact path='/reports' component={Reports}/>
   <Route exact  path='/products' component={Product}/>
   <Route  exact path='/services' component={Services}/>
   <Route  exact path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
   <Route  exact path='/signup'component={Signup}/>
  </Switch>
 </Router>
```